# Why isn't "right click" more used in web applications?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, user-interface

More and more applications are moving to the cloud: Google Docs for productivity apps, Meebo for instant messaging, Gmail for e-mails, Salesforce for CRM, etc.

Yet, I've noticed that, unlike their desktop counterparts, very few of those web apps leverage the mouse's "right click". Most of the time, when right clicking in a web app, I get the standard browser right click menu.

I don't believe it has to do with technical implementation since modifying the right click menu is quite trivial in Javascript.

Is there an actual reason that I am missing?

**EDIT:** The most popular reason seems to be that it's *not what user expect*. Another mentioned reason was that some users disable Javascript - which is a valid answer -, but *in our case*, we can discard this possibility since we're talking about applications that require Javascript *regardless* of the right click option.

Now, let me expand my question a bit:

- Do you think it should stay that way (do you really find the default browser right click menu useful) ?
- Would you like to see more application-specific right click menus where they could improve the user interface ?

Comment: Google Maps has a context dependent right click menu within their app. Just thought I should point that out.

Comment: Come to think of it, double-clicks are also very rare in web apps.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most users expect the right-click menu to bring up the browser context menu, so doing it to bring up an app-specific menu is not something they would try.

Comment: This might be the correct answer today, but I hope that this changes (sooner rather than later). I, for one, want the right-click to be app specific if the browser is hosting an application.  If it's just a web page, then the browser's context menu would be appropriate, otherwise it's actually kind of irritating (to me anyway).

Comment: I don't agree with this. If anything, I'd wager that most users never use right click in a web browser at all, or only by accident.

Comment: And when they do, they're rewarded with... the browser context menu. They quickly learn to not right-click at all.

Comment: Do you guys really think that a valid way to design UI is to reason that "most users are not used to right click, so we should not use it for anything"? It's like saying that "most users are not used to touchscreen, so we should not utilize a touchscreen for anything". Don't be so conservative :-) Right-click is a powerful tool and it should be used more, IMO.

Comment: You're not wrong, but users pick up a habit and never let go unless they're beat over the head. And sometimes not even then.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Who decides what's a "webapp"?  What prevents a page from calling itself a "webapp" just so it can disable my context menu in a silly attempt to prevent me from, say, saving an image, copying a link URL to the clipboard, etc.?  I'd also be uncomfortable allowing random web sites to spoof a browser's context menu (although there's nothing stopping that today).  IMO what's needed is not a way to replace the browser context menu but to augment it, clearly differentiating between context menu items from the web page and ones from the browser.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I agree, we should be able to add page-specific items to the beginning/end of the browser context menu. It annoys the hell out of me that in some browsers, google docs pops up BOTH the browsers menu and the google doc menu on right click as two overlapping menus.. the "right thing" would (always, imho) to have both, integrated as one, and never just one and certainly not both in their own menus.

Comment: @jamesdlin - just like today it's the developer of the website who decides these things. If they do a crappy job in making that decision, then users will have a poor user experience and will dislike the site.  They'll either complain to whoever controls the site, stop using the site, or continue using it while grinding their teeth and growling each time they right click and get something unhelpful. This is nothing new, even for non-web apps.

Comment: @jamesdlin: and of course augmenting the context menu might well be the most appropriate thing - no quarrels there.

Comment: When I click RMB, I do it to access some option I need.  Maybe it's "copy" because I don't have my other hand on the keyboard, maybe it's "add bookmark"...
I don't mind app adding its own entries to the menu but I oppose removing any existing options, and hate you if you take them from me. I have "override context menu" disabled in Firefox prefs, just because some pages do it. My system context menu is more valuable than your potential web app, and "GO AWAY IMAGE THIEF" popup as I try to perform a mouse gesture is causing me to rage.

Answer (score 24):

Mac don't have a "right mouse button", likewise with a lot of touch screen phones etc.

Even on a windows application most normal users (not programmers or power users) don’t think to right clicking when they wish to do something, if they have not learned it off by heart to do the given task they wish to do.

(Also right clicking on most web pages brings up a menu that a normal user does not understand, so they don’t try it more then once.)

**So you always have to provide another way of doing the operation anyway.**

Comment: I think Ian has the right idea.  Mobile computing is quickly gaining traction and there is no "good" way to right click on an Palm Pre/iPhone/Driod/etc...

Comment: That's a very good reason. However, do some touchscreen not simulate "right click" with a prolonged touch (i.e. clicking but not releasing immediately) ?

Comment: @Olivier Do the users of these touchscreen often try a "right click" to see if a usefull menu pops up?  Rightclicking is just something that a lot normal users would never think of doing.

Comment: mac does have a right mouse button. ctrl + click. although i just use a regular mouse

Comment: @Shawn, yes but how many normal mac users would thing to try "ctrl + click"?

Comment: For posterity, virtually all Macs have a right-click, unless they are quite old. Mac users are well acquainted with using a right-click.

Answer (score 15):

I believe a very valid approach to web applications is to still keep all the browser features enabled, such as back button, opening things in new tabs, bookmarking, changing font-sizes, and so on.

The browser's right-click context menu is something that I do not want to have taken away by an app.

Now, when you start moving the web app out of the browser into its own window (turning it into a dedicated application, such as Fluid does, and I believe Chrome OS will), without URL bar and back button, then we can talk about the context-menu.

Comment: I understand that's what keeps developers from making their own right click menu, but I don't see why it has to be so. What do you find so useful in your right click menu ? Personally, I don't ever use it and I'm a web developer. Most controls are available from the top browser menu and other controls can be accessed through shortcuts (ctrl-c,ctrl-v,ctrl-u,etc.).

Comment: "Open link in new tab". About fifty times a day. I don't care if there are other ways to do that. Muscle memory.

Comment: When you have just the mouse in your hand, right-clicking is the fastest way to access anything that's available there.

Comment: From a usability perspective, isn't it faster to middle-click or ctrl-left click to open a link in a new tab? -_-

Comment: @Olivier: That is another big point of contention. Webapps very often do not really have links, as in something that can be opened in a new window, or bookmarked. I concede that if the app is so far removed from a page-flow-based system that it basically just uses the browser as a big canvas, then you might as well take over the right-click menu (I'd rather have such an app be deployed via something like Adobe AIR, though, not in the browser). I suppose most apps we see today are somewhere in the middle.

Comment: An example might be if I'm looking at an Inbox, I want to be able to right-click on a message and get things like Open, Reply, Forward Message.  Choices like "Back" or "View Page Source" are less useful in this context.  And context menus are about *context* aren't they?  I don't care that the Inbox happens to be in a browser - in my mind it's an email application at that point, not a webpage.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Don't screw with my browser.

Comment: @Thilo: It's a little late but most browsers will open links in a new tab if you click on them with your middle mouse button.

Answer (score 4):

It is not how people are used to work in their browser, you shouldn't change default behavior. Users aren't expecting something to happen when they rightclick.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: Opera has no `oncontextmenu` and [no simple](http://code.google.com/p/xuabc/source/browse/trunk/src/domext/oncontextmenu-emulation.js?spec=svn12&r=12) possibility to suppress the context menu on right click.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, this is due to history and what users are used to. But I guess this will be changing eventually, as web applications gain more and more importance; currently web apps are "web pages" in a "web browser" app, which is quite weird, when you think about it. It's not the web browser that's the interesting thing any more, it's the web app. Why should it run inside something called a "browser"? At least it shouldn't be that prominent to the user, even if it may make sense technically.

Actually we're seeing this with Google Chrome. It's definitely way more minimalistic than anything that came before. It's almost a "plain window to the Web".

Comment: I agree. Move it out of the browser into a separate app (like Fluid does for example), remove URL bar and back button, and we can talk about the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

Giving javascript control over right-clicks gives you something like this: http://periodic.lanl.gov/elements/24.html. I really love this website, but its attempts to keep me from copying text or images (whatever it's trying to do) seriously interfere with my web usage patterns. I *always* open things in other tabs. I *always* the right click menu to access the "back" command.

It also irritates me to no end when some web site has a flash animation somewhere that steals my control key (so I can no longer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to flip to another tab.

**My bottom line:** web applications can't supersede the local computer's built in commands. If a web application starts taking over control keys, right clicks, etc., it has crossed the line between local and remote applications. That is a *very* important line to keep crystal clear.

Comment: Yes!  I get thoroughly annoyed when sites steal control away from me, most times, I NEVER go back

Comment: You open new tabs with the right click menu? Did you know you can open links in new tabs using the middle mouse button or ctrl + left click. Thank me later ;)

Comment: My left hand is often busy with my coffee cup, pencil, or holding up my face :P When it's free, I will sometimes control-click, but it's not the same keystroke in all platforms (I split time between WinXP, OSX, and Ubuntu). Right-clicking is platform-neutral.

Comment: @Shawn: On Mac browsers it's usually Command-click, sometimes Option-click.

Comment: The page you mentioned shows me 2 alerts then show me the context menu (at least in firefox)

Comment: @Calmarius - that seems to be new behavior (it does it in Chrome too), I suspect it's interacting poorly with modern javascript engines.

Answer (score 2):

Right click is an expert shortcut both in desktop apps and in the browser. Expert love it, while non-experts ignore it or use it only by rote for specific situations without really understanding it (they probably only use it at all because some expert user told them to). That’s okay. There's nothing wrong with providing something for experts only, either for a thick client or a web app. So, of course, web apps would be better if they included application-specific right click menus. They would also be better if they included accelerator keys for their commands, mnemonics for their pulldown menus, double-click for default actions, and drag and drop for selection, copying, and moving, while we’re on the subject of supporting experts.

Let’s be honest: The reason we don’t do these things for experts is because we don’t want to be bothered with the extra work, not out of some concern about confusing users with the unexpected. And that’s a valid point: a typical web app is used less than a desktop app. “Expert” web app users are thus rarer –few use the web app enough to discover and use the expert features. So why devote resources to something to benefit so few users?

Nonetheless, I want to encourage designers to have application-specific right click menus in their web apps. It is necessary if you want your app to be as usable as a desktop equivalent. If you do have application-specific right click menus, follow these rules:

- All right-click menu commands should be available through a separate means, such as a sidebar menu. With right-click being an expert shortcut, you need to provide non-experts access to the same functionality in a way they’re used to. This rule is a standard (e.g., MS Windows), despite the fact that browsers (e.g., MS Internet Explorer) blatantly violate it. This rule also addresses the concern of users who disable Javascript.
- Do not remove browser right-click commands that are still relevant. The user should still be able do things like save images on a page, copy a block of text, and open a link in a new tab. In fact, you should try to preserve the order of the browser commands as much as sensible. In general, follow the standards for menu item organization and order. This addresses the concern of the right-click menu being unexpected: As long as the same commands are there in pretty much the same order, it’s no cost to the user who is used to right-clicking for the browser commands.
- Use right-click menus consistently. Everything that can have application-specific commands should have those commands available by right-click. If users have to start guessing what does and doesn’t have a right-click menu, they’re just going to give up on it. On the other hand, if they discover it for one item, it’ll encourage them to try it elsewhere, and you want to reward that.
- Encourage right-clicking by showing it used for application specific commands in your advertisements, demos, and documentation. You may also want to explicitly show drop-down arrows on your pages (maybe just on mouse-over) wherever app-specific right-click is available. Some expert users will discover your application-specific commands anyway because they right-click for browser commands, but in many situations, the browser right-click commands are so unhelpful even experts don’t right click, so you may have to “push” it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not what users expect.

It's also not particularly "discoverable": like old-school Flash web sites where you had to roll your mouse over a graphic to get the site to do something, right-clicking is not necessarily intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't fiddle with the right click because of a a little thing we call Best Practices! Don't take away my rights as a user to control my experience!  I want my right click to do what right clicks do!

The best practice is to make this sort of thing optional to the user. If you want to modify this behavior, make it something users can control in their profile or in the application settings.

For example:

```
(click to enable)
[ ] Use super special awesome right-click menu
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, because some people may not have a two-button mouse (I'm looking at you, Apple users).

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a inconsistency between the concept of browsing (which is browser centric) and the use of a web-application (which is application centric, the browser being only the renderer). The right click button would make sense in the second case, but as the web is made for browsing resources, this introduces an ambiguity it will probably never be solved.

Kind of interesting, the fact that the most touted deficiency in macs is the single button mouse, and then the most used interface in the world, the web, is single-button centric.

Comment: Macs have ctrl-click, my dear friend. Most clicks--in fact--are left clicks, but it's nice to have the option.

Comment: In some cases, you can also use click-and-hold to emulate a right click. I am not in favour nor against it. One thing I know for sure is that having a single button forces the developers of horizontal apps to invest more carefully on usability solutions, which is what Apple wants. Clearly, a vertical app like a CAD needs more buttons.

Comment: @thilo: yes yes, I know. I'm a passionate mac user :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two reasons. First of all, people might have javascript turned off, today that might not be the biggest issue of all but it's been following developers since the dawn of web-dev. Which brings us to the second reason, it's not what the users expect.

If you were to talk to someone about usability on the web and you had "hidden" features which were only made visible on right-click(browser context menu popup), this would probably be counted as bad  design just because most users aren't use to the idea that the web is evolving into something more than just links and left-clicks(navigation clicking).

Comment: you got left-clicks and right-clicks backwards in your argument.

Comment: Well that depends on what hand you use for navigation now, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the only time I would do it is if I wrote an app which ran inside a plug-in which emulated some sort of editor.  Silverlight has this ability now, but I would use it sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

As i read in your forst anwser this is true it would be in the context menu it might mess with some things but as i have madde a btoolbar thta floats for my site to do anything you can use keyboard shortcuts so i see a mild and doom future for right click at all i see toolbars everywhree on websites today

Comment: Right. That's why I don't have an iPhone, it has new touch based UI. *sarcasm*