# Contextual Menu Control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, contextmenu

Can anyone recommend a library or a guide in the right direction as to where can I find a Contextual Menu Control for ASP.NET similar to the ones Google uses in its Google Docs or Google Mail web apps ? I looked at the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit as of Sept 2009 and there seems to be none willing to create one.

Answer (score 1):

A contextual menu is just a div containing a few links, positioned at the mouse cursor, and shown on a right click.

You might want to read [Why isn’t “right click” more used in web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055065/why-isnt-right-click-more-used-in-web-applications) before you do it though.